# SSRS Action Inserting Hyperlink to Open an Application

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I've done enough research to insert Hyperlinks into SSRS Data fields but so far no luck on trying to insert a url protocol to open up a third party application.

I'm doing the steps below to add an action to insert the hyperlink using VS2012.

> 1.In the Properties dialog box, click Action.
>
> 2.Select Go to URL. An additional section appears in the dialog box for this option.
>
> 3.In Select URL is where i input my code below: but it doesn't work
>
> `="sp-select://./ordertracking/order?id=" &Fields!guid.Value`
>
> ,it obviously looks for http:// ftp://, https://, and file:// and
>   nothing else so it doesn't work.

How would I be able to get around this issue? sp-select:// is the protocol I need to use to open up the third party application. I've tried using javascript to get around it but still no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try encoding the URL using the URLEncode function. Check [this article](http://capstonebi.blogspot.com.co/2010/04/url-encoding-in-reporting-services.html). It contains an example of a custom function that returns a passed URL encoded properly to be shown in your report.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work :( It now says conversion from type (field) to type 'String' is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Since SSRS protocol for URL action is limited, you can create another column in the SQL select statment like this and point to it from the URL expression.

```
'sp-select://./ordertracking/order?id=' + cast(oi.guid as nvarchar (80)) as 'column'
```

it will then ignore the protocols to be used and still launch the address of the text of this field.